# Create a Custom Link in Admin section django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm finding a way to create a custom link like "Add" or "Change" for each section model.

I have Voucher model which current have add and change link. But, I want to add a new Add link with it (in which i want to add 3 more custom fields which are not present in first add link)

[image]

Comment: Why need of question? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin AND https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41 It is already well documented.

Comment: @AnupYadav Actions are different things

Comment: You need to override the admin templates in django project.
You need to copy specific templates into you project `/project_path/templates/admin/`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I want for some models an additional import link. Did you find a solution to add a URL in models or admin with an attribute to use in the template like add_url or change_url?